# Algorithm to check whether rational polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: irreducible-polynomials, computer-algebra-systems

Let $F\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ a multivariate polynomial. Is there an algorithm for checking whether $F$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$? Is this implemented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GIAC](https://www-fourier.univ-grenoble-alpes.fr/%7Eparisse/giac/doc/fr/cascmd_fr/index.html) to factorize a multivariate polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$:

```
complex_mode = 1
p = 3/2*x^2*y^2+x^2+3*x*y^3/2+x*y
factor(p)
```

output: `(3*y^2+2)*x*(x+y)/2`.